# Why is environment variable ignored, if setting exists in appsetings.json?

Tags: asp.net-core

Here is my program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build()
        .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Nothing special.

In `appsettings.json` file I have a setting:

```
{
    "Integrations" : {
        "Pipedrive" : {
            "ApiToken" : "some value"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have also set variable `ASPNETCORE_INTEGRATIONS__PIPEDRIVE__APITOKEN`.

If I remove key from `appsettings.json` file, Configuration returns me same value as environment variable has.

However, if key exists in settings file, I get value from the file.
 Moreover, I can see that `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` comes after `JsonConfigurationProvider`.

And the weirdest thing here is that when I try in `Immediate Window`:

```
Configuration.GetValue<string>("ASPNETCORE_Integrations:Pipedrive:ApiToken");
```

I get the value assigned to the environment variable.

Can anyone explain me, why in one case `ASPNETCORE_` prefix is ignored, and in the other it is not.

I do not configure host or application configuration explicitly.

Comment: This is not a true answer so will make it a comment..  I believe its by design.. Tangentially I know that when I publish to azure.   I set "Environment Variables" by adding to `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

For environment variables, sections have to be denoted with some sort of delimiter. That's usually `:`, though apparently double-underscore (`__`) works as well. However, `ASPNETCORE_` only has a single-underscore, so it's interpreted as one token with `INTEGRATIONS`. However, even if you had a double-underscore there as well, it still wouldn't override your JSON, because the JSON has no `ASPNETCORE` section.

Long and short, drop the `ASPNETCORE_` bit. The environment variable name must match your JSON sections *exactly* (with the delimiter being present between each section name) or nothing will be overridden.

Comment: But why is it returned when json does not have the key? It is correctly resolved by `Configuration.GetValue<string>("Integrations:Pipedrive:ApiToken");`

Comment: Not sure, honestly. The only way that would make sense is if there's some internal logic in the configuration key retrieval that explicitly strips off `ASPNETCORE_` if it's found. Then, I guess if the JSON setting is there, the key is found directly without resorting to said fallback. Totally guessing here though.

Comment: However, I will say that `ASPNETCORE_` is basically a namespace, and should be treated as such. That's probably why whatever logic is causing this is there: to enable internal configuration. While it's unlikely your *exact* key would be also used by the ASP.NET Core team at some point, it's better to stay out of people's namespaces.

Comment: its returned probably because "*AddEnvironmentVariables is automatically called for environment variables prefixed with ASPNETCORE_ when you initialize a new WebHostBuilder.*". ref:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider

Comment: btw, remove api keys from `appsettings.json` as its a bad practice anyways. use `launchSettings.json` to set environment variables if you want them or go with key vault.

Comment: @deezg No, I am not placing values there, actually, I write there a comment, that for dev either set environment variable or use manager =)

Comment: @deezg Found the explanation. Host configuration is merged as a `ChainedConfugrationProvider` which contains config with `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider` with the required prefix `ASPNETCORE_`.

And regular provider is registered without the prefix.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I was just playing with configuration, I'll use another prefix, and register it explicitly.